# Add Content to jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-datepicker

Client needs blue and yellow "dots" in certain days in a Calendar. I've got a handle on the dots (simple CSS) but am looking for guidance on what would be the best way to get these added (and where) to the datepicker. I have modified the datepicker for mobile (just FYI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: the numerical days are housed inside  tags so one would simply find those that you are needing (say 15) and add the css

```
$("td > a:contains('15')").addClass('yellowDot');
```